# Sha-3 in python implementation

Tags: python, sha-3, keccak

I am trying to implement sha-3 in python.The code given below is how I implemented it.But i am getting the below error again and again.

```
import sys 
import hashlib
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
with open(arg1, 'r') as myfile:
     data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
import sha3
s=hashlib.sha3_228(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(s)
```

The following error is what i get when I execute it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sha3.py", line 6, in <module>
import sha3
File "/home/hello/Documents/SHA-3/sha3.py", line 7, in <module>
s=hashlib.sha3_228(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha3_228'
```

The below link can be used for reference.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3

Comment: You are trying to use it, not implement it. Implementing means to write code that does the actual hash calculation. That's not what you're doing here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here: one from your code, and one from the documentation, that contains a typo on the function you would like to use.

You are calling a function that is not present in `hashlib` library. You want to call function `sha3_228` from module `sha3`, that is shipped with package `pysha3`. In fact, `sha3_228` does not exist, it is `sha3_224` that exists.

Simply replace `hashlib.sha3_228` with `sha3.sha3_224`.

And make sure you have installed `pysha3`, with command

```
python -m pip install pysha3
```

Here is an example

```
import sha3
data='maydata'
s=sha3.sha3_224(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(s)
# 20faf4bf0bbb9ca9b3a47282afe713ba53c9e243bc8bdf1d670671cb
```

Comment: Small note here: Sha3 is supported in Python 3.6 (as well as a few other added algorithms)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I installed sha3 by itself first. That doesn't work.  Then I installed pysha3 and it still didn't work.  I finally uninstalled both sha3 and pysha3.  Then I reinstalled just pysha3 and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You likely need to include:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3, 6):
    import sha3
```

This is because is lower versions of python sha3 aren't included by default in hashlib.